# Another way to say "octupled"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests

It's common in science to say something doubled (x2) or even quadrupled (x4) or quintupled (x5). However, higher orders of change are less frequently written in this form. The only exceptions are changes of 10x, 100x, 1000x , etc., which are often referred to as changes in "[order(s) of magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_magnitude)."

This leads to my question: If I have a value that has octupled, is there another way to refer to this increase by avoiding usage of the uncommon word "octuple?"

- "Increased 8x (*or 8 times*) seems more like informal speech being placed into text, but perhaps I'm wrong about that.
- Does "increased by an order of eight" work?
- Or perhaps, it's more appropriate to say "increased by a *factor* of 8"?

Comment: In what sense is this an exact duplicate of "How can I form a word like “quadruple” for any number I want?"  It's a completely different question.

Comment: @SimonB erm... the answer given in the original question explains "how" and "what" to do, it suggests using the suffix **-fold**. A much more useful answer to visitors than the one supplied by user383etc...

Comment: @SimonB it is not necessary for both questions to be exact duplicates of one another. Of course, the wording will more often than not be different but if the request is very similar and the answers in the older question also fit the newer question than that's a good reason for closing.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - good reason for closing? How could the OP ever find the “duplicate” question whose title is far from  being close to what he is looking for. Plus the OP is not looking for a general answer but for a specific one about octupled, and eightfold as suggested below and in the “duplicate” answer are just one of the possible answers. CV mania hits agein!!

Comment: @user3850720 cast your vote to reopen, if you haven't already. And if you feel so strongly ask Robusto why he chose to close it singlehandedly.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - he closed it because the question reminded him of the answer he gave in the "duplicate" question.  And without a second thought, he put it on hold. That the CV function is often abused is no surprise,   this is just another example.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the expression ***[eightfold:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/eightfold)***

> eight times as big or as much:
> *an eightfold increase*

(Cambridge Dictionary)