# What is it called when you multiply something eight times?

Tags: single-word-requests

I know that the prefix for eight is "oct". Does this mean that the word I am looking for starts with"oct"? I have done quite a bit of research. Almost every time the first website listed is this one. I really hope that this will be the end of my research! Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for a word in the sequence *double, triple, quadruple, ...*

Comment: Please give us an example.  It’s not clear whether you mean n*8,  n^8,  or n*(m^8), etc

Comment: Single word requests must be accompanied by an example sentence.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Another way to say "octupled"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/444635/another-way-to-say-octupled)

Answer (score 8):

***[Octuple:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/octuple)***

> to make eight times as much or as many.
>   (M-W)

Or

[Eightfold:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/eightfold)

> (Mathematics) by or up to eight times as much.

(Collins English Dictionary)

Comment: A verb 'to octuple' is certainly morphologically well_formed, but I think it is rare, and for good reasons.  I think that 'sextuple' is at the limit of widely used multiples.  'Septuple' begins to sound a bit odd, 'octuple' somehow less so, but nine times?  Nonuple?  Surely not. As for 'ninefold' (by analogy with 'eightfold'), you cannot 'ninefold' something.  You might increase it nineford.

Comment: Octuplicate, octuplication. Hmm, not sure how I feel about this. Tempted to octify.